Azure Data Factory - Scale up the Elasticpool with web activity
I'm trying to scale my Azure elasticpool in datafactory with a web activity task passing the following api call:
{
    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subID/resourceGroups/RGNAME/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlservername/elasticPools/elasticpoolname?api-version=2021-11-01",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "sku": {
            "name": "GP_Gen5",
            "tier": "GeneralPurpose",
            "capacity": "50

4"
        },
        "location": "West Europe"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
    }
}

The web activity fails, but the scale up operation actually works. Even though the scaling works I obviously don't want the activity to fail.
I have tried with contributor and SQL Server Contributor roles for my ADF as these roles contains the 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/elasticPoolOperationResults/read' action.
Here is the error,
"error": {
    "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client 'ADF ID' with object id 'ADF ID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/elasticPoolOperationResults/read' over scope '/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/RGNAME/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/westeurope/elasticPoolOperationResults/id' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
}

Any idea? what is missing here?
I have tried adding the required permission to the ADF to call the REST API for scaling up the elastic pool, but it's not working.
As per the MS documentation, it should work docs

To scale up Elastic pool using below configuration:

Web activity fails, but the scale up operation actually works as shown below:

It may be bug. check this bug request or raise support ticket.
